# Remix automatically reverting token deployment to address only

Tags: token, contract, remix, bscscan

I copied a contract with pragma experimental ABI I found to play around with the features on testnet.

Contract copied:
https://bscscan.com/address/0x68590a47578e5060a29fd99654f4556dbfa05d10#code and here is my testnet contract deployed to the BSC: https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xb7030b205dfec92df0a9eacc1b418c39df77c3a0

When compiling, I've tried optimization enabled, and disabled. Auto compile enabled and disabled. Same issue either way. Only the address gets compiled.
Compiler defaults to just the address, so I use the drop down in the compiler menu and selected the part of the contract with the token name. As soon as I hit "Compile," the contract drop down automatically reverts back to just the address.

I tried seeing if it would let me deploy the contract by selecting the part of contract with the token name in the deployment screen, even though it appears to only want to compile the address.
Doesn't work either.

It only compiles the address while my wallet is connected to mainnet as well. Not sure what causes this?

Answer (score 0):

Remix compiles all contracts in the file, when you hit the Compile button.

[image: Compile options screen]

> *As soon as I hit "Compile," the contract drop down automatically reverts back to just the address.*

I agree that this is a bit annoying.

But you can still chose the specific contract to deploy - in the "Deploy & run transactions" tab.

[image: Deploy and run transactions screen]

Comment: Thanks. I had did that. I figured out my issue. I was using PancakeSwap V2 router address instead of testnet router address, so was getting gas revert error.